# How to take data (sensors) from the smartphone?

Tags: android, smartphone

I want to create something using data from my smartphone, for example, from it's acelerometer, or maybe a whatsapp mensage, or from a photo take the dominant color (red for example) and if the color is the color of my desire them activate the lamp in my house (using arduino)
I want to take the data use it in other device. How do I do it?

Thank you very much for your time and your answer.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials regarding Android software development and Arduino which you can find online. This site works best with specific programming questions.

Comment: This is very abstract